# Laravel Auth session losing when redirect pages

Tags: php, session, authentication, redirect, laravel

I have a auth problem with laravel sessions. (It was working in same system before)

This is my user controller

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $username = Input::get("username");
    $password = Input::get("password");
    $credentials = array
    (
        "username"=> $username,
        "password" => $password,
    );
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
    {
        echo Auth::user()->username;
        exit();

    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to("user/login")->with("error_msg","Giriş Başarısız! <br>Lütfen girdiğiniz bilgileri kontrol edip yeniden deneyin.");
    }
}
```

It returns username.. But when i redirect page session is losing.

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $username = Input::get("username");
    $password = Input::get("password");
    $credentials = array
    (
        "username"=> $username,
        "password" => $password,
    );
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('check_login');

    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to("user/login")->with("error_msg","Giriş Başarısız! <br>Lütfen girdiğiniz bilgileri kontrol edip yeniden deneyin.");
    }
}
```

And My Route:

```
Route::get("check_login",function(){
    echo Auth::user()->username;
});
```

The result:

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
echo Auth::user()->username;
```

Comment: Check your `session.php` config file. Does the `domain` and `path` settings match with your dev environment?

Comment: I checked the session.php they are the default settings
'path' => '/',
'domain' => null,

Comment: Are you working on a vhost environment? What is the session driver? If you're trying to log in an url like `http://localhost/myproject/public/` or something like that it could be the problem.

Comment: Im not working in a vhost. My session drive is file. Url is a real domain. And when i test it before it was working.

Answer (score 1):

Check your route for `postLogin()` function. If you are using in `UserController`, it should be below for `post` method.

```
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'UserController@postLogin'));
```

Function and route that you provided is working perfectly with me, but if you want to check the user is saved in session or not, try like this.

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    echo 'My user is logged in';
}
```

It is better if you can provide all routes you are using for that.

Answer (score 1):

use database session, more info: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#database-sessions

OR

I got the same problem. & found problem with my code

in my controller:

```
public function login(Request $request){
    //assign $request data to session
    Session::put('price',$request->price);
}
public function checkLogin(){
    if(login fail){
    redirect back to login
    }
}
```

when i redirect to login session override to empty because when I redirect, $request is empty
so 'price' is empty

so I check session already got value before put into session

```
public function login(Request $request){
    //check session already got value
    if(Session::get('price') == ""){

    //assign $request data to session
    Session::put('price',$request->price);
    }
}
```

problem solved for me.

hope it helps to anyone have same problem